# BufferedReader Not Reading Correctly

Tags: java

For some reason, When using my buffered reader to read a .mcf (Map Configuration File), It will not correctly find the characters. This is what I'm using for testing purpose.

RendererPanel.java:

```
        File file = new File("src/net/PlatformPeril/resources/Railroad.mcf");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
            System.out.println("Air Block!");
        }else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            System.out.println("Rock Block!");
        }else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
            System.out.println("Empty Line Char; Ignoring");
            continue;
        }else System.out.println("What!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

MCF:

```
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And, I'm getting alot of 'What!'....
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the 'line' simply printing out gibberish? or just not the lines you were expecting?

Comment: Just always saying "What!" cause I'm reading lines; not per char.

Comment: I've found two definitions of 'Map Configuration File': one is XML and the other looks a bit like like JSON. Neither of them has lines consisting of, or starting with, "0", "1", ... So what is *this* format?

Comment: I agree with @EJP - show us a few lines of the mcf file. It's not clear what the data format is.

Comment: Updated Forum with format.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the entire line when you should be comparing the first token, look at string.split to help

Answer (score 0):

This `line.equalsIgnoreCase(" "`) may cause problems, try `line.trim().isEmpty()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Let the file contains the following-

0

1

0

1

consider a blank line

1

The below program works fine, same as yours but with certain refinements.

```
package com.kvvssut.misc;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferReaderTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processFile("C:\\Users\\srimanta_sahu\\Desktop\\MyText.mcf");
    }

    private static void processFile(String string) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(new File(string));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                currentLine = currentLine.trim();
                if(currentLine.equals("0")){
                    System.out.println("Air Block!");
                } else if (currentLine.equals("1")){
                    System.out.println("Rock Block!");
                } else if(currentLine.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("Empty Line Char; Ignoring");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("What!");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    fileReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Plz dont use unnecessary equalsIgnoreCase for checking integers and dont use continue if it doesnt have to do anything!